# Drawing Image size auto-increases, System.Drawing.Image, C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawing, gdi

I want to draw an image by reading it
from file sytem image file, and render
it on a document, below:

> ```
> if (File.Exists(imageFilePath))   //all image file are 16*16 in pixel
>                 {
>                     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(18, 18);
>                     Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
>
>                     Image image = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
>                     graphics.DrawImage(image, 1, 1); //1 pixel space in between
>                 }
> ```
>
> However, gray images renders the
>   correct size (18*18 in pixel),
>   whereas, colour images are cut off, or
>   have to increase the BitMap size (e.g.
>   Bitmap(23, 23). I want to all images
>   have the same size! The image sizes
>   are all the same on the file system.

It is a bit of urgency. Any idea would
be very much appreicated!

Solution below:

```
   if (File.Exists(imageFilePath))
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(18, 18);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

                Image image = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 1, 1, **18, 18**);                  

            }
```

Comment: Can you post samples of your B&W and color image files? It sounds as if your color image is not really 16x16. Also, what format are your files?  *.ico, *.png, *.jpeg, *bmp?

Comment: Since you're resizing the color image, you'll probably want to make sure you explicitly set `graphics.InterpolationMode` to bicubic.